# Meaning of a immutable name in julia package

Tags: julia

I just downloaded the package RandomMatrices.jl to julia because I need to compute the Tracy-Widom densities. However the docs does not help me much in understanding what does it mean:

```
immutable TracyWidom <: ContinuousUnivariateDistribution
end
```

What kind of type is this `TracyWidom` name? What should I supply in order to do some tests with the function

```
pdf(d::TracyWidom, t::Real)
```

contained in TracyWidom.jl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package defines a `TracyWidom` type, which has no fields. You can create a new instance of the `TracyWidom` type by typing `TracyWidom()`.

To calculate the PDF of the `TracyWidom` distribution, use `pdf(TracyWidom(), 0.5)`.

You can figure this out from the `pdf` type signature: the first argument should be an object of type `TracyWidom`, and the second of type `Real`.

Julia has a [rich type system](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/), but relevant for here are the following: `abstract`, which can't be created, `immutable`, which can't be modified after being created, and `type` which is the "normal" kind.

In [Distributions.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/blob/master/src/univariate/normal.jl), which this is based off, there are types defined for each distribution, e.g. the normal distribution is

```
immutable Normal <: ContinuousUnivariateDistribution
    μ::Float64
    σ::Float64
    # Some other stuff...
end
```

which makes more sense because its defined by those two parameters - `TracyWidom` doesn't need any parameters, but we still follow the same style. The `<: ContinuousUnivariateDistribution` means that `Normal` and `TracyWidom` are both `ContinuousUnivariateDistribution`s, which is an abstract type.

Comment: Can you change now->no in the first sentence? StackOverflow won't let me do edits with less than 6 characters!

Comment: Done, fixed another typo too.